# Transition from UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, animation, transition

Could recommend me any third part library to animate custom transition to new view controller directly from UITableView, where cells slides out (up and down) and smoothly transmit with opacity to new controller.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you code put in some gesture recognizers and set them as IBActions to segue to a different view controller.

In general you could just set an animation when a button as a clicked, to play the animation and then open a new view controller.